# Would you have the fingering for the left hand of these two measures?

Tags: fingering

The score below is "Moldau", transcripted for piano.

**On the measure number 24 (second on the scan), on left hand, should we really play "thumb (1) thumb (1)" and keep the B white doted note during the six first notes.

**For the measure number 25 (third on the scan), on left hand, keeping the B whited doted note seems not feasible ?
What should be the fingering of the six first notes of this measure, left hand ?

[image]

Comment: Whatever you  do, holding low B while playing the two Cs is too much of a stretch for some - including me. Pedalling isn't a good option, either sustain or sostenuto, as either would hold the treble notes too.

Comment: @Tim : sorry, I'm lost. You seem say that holding low B is too difficult and that pedalling is not good, so are you meaning that there is *no solution* / that it is impossible ?

Comment: I'm saying it's impossible for *me* Players with a span of a 9th or tenth wouldn't find it difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Measure 24

The intention is that the left hand B is held through the entirety of both measures. However, the problematic C in the left hand can be taken by the right hand instead.

Notice here in the [Kàan arrangement](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/a/ab/IMSLP335758-SIBLEY1802.26409.7272-39087012862209vltava.pdf), from which the OP arrangement seems to be adapted, the B is tied across both measures 24 and 25, and the C is notated in the upper staff.

**"Vlatava" Arr. Kàan, mm. 22-27**

[image: "Vlatava" Arr. Kàan, mm. 22-27]

#### Measure 25

There are at least two options for measure 25:

1. For the left-hand sixteenth notes, use the fingering `1-2-1-2-3-2   1-2-1-2-1-2`.
2. The right hand could pick up some of the left hand notes. For example, the third and/or fourth left-hand sixteenths (G and F#) could be taken by the right-hand thumb. Similarly and of the seventh through eleventh left-hand sixteenths could be played with the right-hand thumb, depending on the fingering chosen for the right hand.

Note again the arrangement of notes and the fingering given in the example above.